# No class def found error in server

Tags: java, ant, noclassdeffounderror

I am writing a SCP client application and i am using ant-jsch to scp the file to remote server.
Scp client works fine in my debug setup (eclipse set up). The file is copied to remote server.

But when i put the code in server and try to run scp client i get following error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6:159-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/Task
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
```

The jar files are at appropriate places and when class path is exported i can see those jar files. I am not class not found is coming for org.apache.tools.ant.Task not for the scp class (org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp) itself.

Is this because of any dependencies which eclipse solved on its own and i need to solve it manually in my application server?

Regards
Dheeraj Joshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. We need ant-1.6.jar to run this. Not just ant.jar

Answer (score 1):

yes ant.jar must be in your classpath in which you execute scp command

Comment: Yes ant.jar is also present in the classpath

Comment: echo $classpath
/root/ant.jar:/root/ant-jsch-1.6.jar:/root/jsch-0.1.48.jar

javac Test.java